# There is no continuous bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1] \times [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

> How to show
>
> There is no continuous bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ ?

My Try:

I think, between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, continuous onto function exist. But the one to one continuous map does not exist.

Is my guess correct?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510573/is-there-a-continuous-bijection-between-an-interval-and-a-square-0-1-mapsto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Take a point out of both $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. Then one is connected, while the other is not.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Certainly this is the way to go; however, there are two points you can take out of $[0,1]$ to preserve connectedness.  If we're picking points at random though, it's true that $[0,1]^2$ is guaranteed connectedness whereas $[0,1]$ is not.

Comment: This actually only proves there is no continuous bijection **with a continuous inverse** between the two sets (i.e., it shows the two sets are not homeomorphic.

Comment: @5xum Yes, we need the compactness of $[0,1]$ and the Hausdorffness of $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ to show that every continuous bijection is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @KajHansen Indeed there are two non-cut points of $[0,1]$. Thanks for pointing it out. :)